# Wrong betweenness in both Networkx and Networkit?

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory, networkit

Apparently, both node betweenness and edge betweenness calculated with networkx and networkit give different values than what supposed to be.

Lets consider the following undirected graph ([pag. 20/85 in these Lecture notes](http://www2.unb.ca/%7Eddu/6634/Lecture_notes/Lecture_4_centrality_measure.pdf)), written as edge list and saved in `mygraph.txt`:

```
1 2
1 5
2 3
2 5
3 4
4 5
4 6
```

The node betweenness should be ([pag. 20/85 in these Lecture notes](http://www2.unb.ca/%7Eddu/6634/Lecture_notes/Lecture_4_centrality_measure.pdf)):

```
Node | Betweenness
1 0
2 1.5
3 1
4 4
5 3
6 0
```

However, by running the following code (I used `G1` and `G2` as different names for the graph in networkx and networkit, but they are exactly the same graph, coming from the same file `mygraph.txt`):

```
import networkx as nx
from networkit import *  
import networkit as nk 


G1 = nx.read_edgelist("mygraph.txt",create_using=nx.Graph(), nodetype = int)
G1.number_of_nodes()

node_btw = nx.betweenness_centrality(G1, normalized=False)
edge_btw = nx.edge_betweenness_centrality(G1, k=None, normalized=False, weight=None, seed=None)

print('NETWORK-X')
print(node_btw.values())
print(edge_btw.values())


edgeListReader = nk.graphio.EdgeListReader(' ', 1)
G2 = nk.readGraph("/home/JohnRambo/Documents/myFolder/mygraph.txt", nk.Format.EdgeListTabOne)
print(G2.numberOfNodes(), G2.numberOfEdges()) 

G2.indexEdges()
btwn = nk.centrality.Betweenness(G2, normalized=False, computeEdgeCentrality=True)
btwn.run()

print('NETWORK-IT')
print(btwn.scores()[:10])
print(btwn.edgeScores()[:10])
```

I got these results (P.S.: I added manually the texts `node betweenness` and `edge betweenness`):

```
NETWORK-X
node betweenness: [0.0, 1.5, 3.0, 1.0, 4.5, 0.0]
edge betweenness: [2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 2.5, 5.5, 3.5, 5.0]

NETWORK-IT
node betweenness: [0.0, 3.0, 2.0, 9.0, 6.0, 0.0]
edge betweenness: [4.0, 7.0, 7.0, 6.0, 5.0, 11.0, 10.0]
```

My calculation gives different results (the node betweenness scores are in agreement with those ones shown at [pag. 20/85 in these Lecture notes](http://www2.unb.ca/%7Eddu/6634/Lecture_notes/Lecture_4_centrality_measure.pdf))

```
node betweenness: [0.0, 1.5, 1.0, 4.5, 3.0, 0.0]
edge betweenness: [2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 2.5, 3.5, 5.5, 5.0]
```

**Could you be please clarify and suggest a way to fix this issue?**

Comment: You're calculations are the same as networkx up to reordering, and the same as networkit up to reordering and multiplication by 2.  Are you sure networkx and networkit are outputting results in the order you expect?

Comment: Also reading your file top to bottom, the nodes encountered in that order are `1 2 5 3 4 6`.  That reordering applied to the result from networkx reorders it to your calculation.

Comment: Many thanks @KyleParsons for your reply - If we consider the NODE BETWEENNESS, Networkx gives the values in the order you mentioned, i.e. `1 2 5 3 4 6`... that means that networkx is labelling nodes from top to down and from left to right (i.e. 1st row left, 1st row right, 2nd row left, 2nd row right, 3rd row left, etc...), and it stores a label once it finds a new label/number.. that would explain the messy order... Instead networkit gives the correct order from `1` to `6`, i.e. `1 2 3 4 5 6`... Therefore, networkx and networkit use different "logics" to store labels and calculated values...

Comment: In addition, Yes, networkit gives the correct order but a double value...

Comment: Now, if we consider instead the EDGE BETWEENNESS, networkx gives the correct order (i.e. as written in the `mygraph.txt` file) and the correct value, **except** for the 5th edge's value which is switched with the 6th edge's one.... Instead, networkit gives the correct values, but double and in a different order.. However, which is the logic behind that order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kyle mentions in his comment, the nodes in the network are added in
the sequence associated with the edgelist. To remedy this, a simple
sort will fix it. The third line of output shows the actual sequence
of nodes.

With respect to the edges, something unexpected happened with reading
the edge list from file: the edge (4, 5) is loaded as (5, 4). See
second line of output. This causes the expected sort order of the
edges, which would be like the file, to be different: the sixth and
seventh node are swapped.

The code below sorts the node betweenness dictionary by key values
(the node number), while putting the betweenness values in a tuple,
output in the fourth line.

The last lines show each edge with its betweenness value.

```
import networkx as nx

G1 = nx.read_edgelist("mygraph.txt",create_using=nx.Graph(), nodetype = int)
G1.number_of_nodes()

node_btw = nx.betweenness_centrality(G1, normalized=False)
edge_btw = nx.edge_betweenness_centrality(G1, k=None, normalized=False, weight=None, seed=None)

print('NETWORK-X')
print(tuple(node_btw.keys()))
print(tuple(edge_btw.keys()))
nn_btw = tuple(v for _,v in sorted(node_btw.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]))
print(nn_btw)
en_btw = tuple(v for _,v in sorted(edge_btw.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]))
print(en_btw)
for k,v in sorted(edge_btw.items(),key=lambda x: x[0]):
    print(k, v)
```

Output:

```
# NETWORK-X
# (1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 6)
# ((1, 2), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 5), (5, 4), (3, 4), (4, 6))
# (0.0, 1.5, 1.0, 4.5, 3.0, 0.0)
# (2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 2.5, 3.5, 5.0, 5.5)
# (1, 2) 2.0
# (1, 5) 3.0
# (2, 3) 3.5
# (2, 5) 2.5
# (3, 4) 3.5
# (4, 6) 5.0
# (5, 4) 5.5
```

Comment: Oh thanks a lot @VirtualScooter, very kind! .....will the same code sort the edge betweenness as well?

Comment: You're welcome, @limone. Yes, the edge betweenness can be sorted in a similar way (sort by first node, then by second node of the edge). I've updated the answer with code for that. Also, this is different from the way the file lists the edges. If that is important, then one could consider labeling the edges and sorting by label.
If you like my answer, please consider accepting it and upvoting it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @VirtualScooter! Btw, I am still thinking to what possible reason could make Networkx read the edges list in a different way from what I wrote in the txt file (I refer to: "With respect to the edges, something unexpected happened with reading the edge list from file: the edge (4, 5) is loaded as (5, 4)")......

Comment: Hi @VirtualScooter... I just checked again and I have noticed that your output gives the following values: edge '(3.4)' value '5.0', edge '(4,5)' value '3.5', edge '(4.6)' value '5.5'. However, my aforementioned calculation gives edge '(3.4)' value '3.5', edge '(4,5)' value '5.5', edge '(4.6)' value '5.0'. Therefore, it looks like it is not a correct output... right?

Comment: Actually, it is the correct output. Let me change the program slightly so that the edges are listed alongside the betweenness values.